# Find out which program reads from a given MSMQ queue

Tags: msmq

I have a queue that should only be read by a specific program. However, I have discovered that some other program is "stealing" messages from that queue. Is there a way to determine which program does that? I couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given service account, set read-message and peek-message permissions on the queue, and then ensure that only the consumer runs under that service account.

**UPDATE**

On Windows server 2008 or Windows 7 or higher, MSMQ has a dedicated system event log which records everything the MSMQ subsystem does. It may be possible to see what user account is accessing the queue via this.

Comment: Yes, I did that; I was hoping there was a method to find out what program reads from that queue, though, not just to disable it. If there's no other answer today I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: Thanks - that is good to know for the future, unfortunately that server is Windows 2003. (We plan on moving to 2008.) I found the culprit, incidentally, I just want to know in case this happens again. For now, I'll mark your answer as accepted, thanks.